# Как сделать повторяющиеся уведомления с разным текстом на Андройд

Tags: android, уведомления

Мне нужно показывать еженедельно уведомления, начиная с даты, выбранной пользователем. И в этом уведомлении показывать разный текст.
Видел как некоторые приложения показывают ежедневно уведомления и показывают количество дней, сколько пользователь не заходил в приложение или не выполнял какие-то определенные функции (нажатия) внутри самого приложения. Подскажите, как или с помощью чего это реализовано.

А пока приходится создавать уведомления через циклы, используя:

```
       AlarmHelper alarmHelper = AlarmHelper.getInstance();
       for (int i = currentWeek + 1; i < 21; i++) {
            alarmCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
            long time = alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
            alarmHelper.setWeekAlarm(getApplicationContext(), WeekReceiver.class, time, i, i);
       }
```

И `AlarmHelper` класс ниже

```
public class AlarmHelper {

    private static AlarmHelper instance;

    public static AlarmHelper getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new AlarmHelper();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public void setWeekAlarm(Context context, Class<?> receiver, long time, int week, int req_code) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, receiver);
        intent.putExtra("week_title", "your week " + week);
        intent.putExtra("req_code", req_code);

        //cancel already existed alarm
        cancelWeekAlarm(context, receiver, req_code);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, req_code, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
    }

    public void cancelWeekAlarm(Context context, Class<?> receiver, int req_code) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, receiver);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, req_code, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        pendingIntent.cancel();
    }
}
```

Код работает, и уведомления показываются раз в неделю с отображением текущей недели. Но скорее всего я выбрал не тот подход к решению моего вопроса, и может вы подскажете, как можно реализовать это проще?

Comment: То же предстоит такое делать и как раз хотел попробовать такой вариант. Так как Вы уже это попробовали, то хотел бы уточнить - а что именно Вам в данном подходе не нравится? Есть какие то учечки или какие то фризы? Что именно не подошло?

Comment: Да вот пытаюсь разобраться, эффективен ли данный метод. Как я уже писал, одно приложение показывает каждый день уведомления и отсчет дней, сколько не заходил в приложение. Можно не заходить 300 дней, и он на 300й день покажет в констекте значение 300. Не думаю что это реализовано таким способом.

Comment: Если нужно фиксировать дату последнего входа, то я бы при входе в приложение записывал в шаредпреференс дату, потом из не вытаскивал и сверял.

Comment: А в сторону FireBase не смотрели?

Comment: Так и делаю, при входе. Firebase еще не смотрел.